# Painting inside a java window natively

Tags: java, windows, camera, jna

I am using direct Show capture graph to preview camera in a native lib (C++).
I want to paint the camera preview on a java window , how should I do this using JNA and java?

I can pass the window handle using JNI , but is painting on the native side on a java window going to create any problem ?

Comment: I would suggest trying to have a look at something the java bindings for VLC, which do a similar sort of thing

Comment: You need to ensure you pass the handle of a heavyweight component (java.awt.Panel, java.awt.Window, or java.awt.Frame) so that Java can manage its stacking appropriately.  You may need to override the component's `.paint()` method so that Java completely avoids attempting to paint into that window.